# [process exited with code 1], can't open WSL, zsh

Tags: zsh, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I get `[process exited with code 1]` when I try to access a WSL distro.  This happened after removing zsh using command: `sudo apt-get remove zsh`.

[image: Screenshot of error reads "process exited with code 1"]

Comment: Perhaps it was defined as your login shell? Why did you remove it?

Comment: Just a friendly, neighborhood reminder that questions on Stack Overflow should be regarding *"specific coding, algorithm, or language problems."* Your question would likely be better suited for [Super User](https://superuser.com), [Unix & Linux Stack](https://unix.stackoverflow.com), or potentially [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com), but please be sure to familiarize yourself with those sites' rules for posting as well.

Comment: In case you haven't corrected this. You can go to Start and find "Ubuntu For Windows" then right click on it. Go to "More" and choose "App Settings." It will open a window where you can "Reset" Ubuntu or "Repair." I accidentally chose "Reset" and had to reinstall Ubuntu which took a few seconds. This solved problem but del files. "Repair" was probably the better option.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

i remove zsh and forget to set bash as default shell.

So i did this and its work now;

Login with root `wsl -u root`

and then execute this command `chsh -s /bin/bash <username>`

restart terminal and that it.

Best regards !

Comment: Thank you! Lifesaver. This should be accepted answer.

Comment: Definitely saved me, up voted

Answer (score 1):

This happened with me after I uninstalled zsh from wsl2

You need to change default terminal to use bash instead of zsh which you can do by first installing zsh and then setting bash as default

- Step 1:go to windows PowerShell C:\WINDOWS\system32>

  `wsl.exe -e sudo apt-get install zsh`
- Step 2: restart Windows terminal and

  Change `/etc/pam.d/chsh`: from:

  ```
  `auth       required   pam_shells.so`
  ```

  to

  ```
  `auth       sufficient   pam_shells.so`
  ```
- Step 3:

  `chsh -s /bin/bash root`